# Is Time Datatype in SQL Server 2008 R2 supports Entityframework with MVC4

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-2008-r2, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using ASP.NET MVC4 with Entityframework.

Does Entityframework supports new Time datatype of SQL.

Thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes it is supported. If you have table which uses `Time` SQL type it will be recognized as `EDM.Time` and generated entity will use `TimeSpan` as property type. In the same way it works with code first approach. If you map property with `TimeSpan` type the table will contain SQL `Time` column.